# Why decorator-style context manager in Python doesn't catch exception within Tkinter window?

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

there is a simple code with decorator-generated context manager via contextlib. When I press button exception raised and DOES NOT handled by context manager. Why is it?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
from contextlib import contextmanager


def close_window(): 
    window.destroy()
    raise Exception


@contextmanager
def safe():
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print 'Exception catched'

with safe():
    window = Tk()
    button = Button(window, text='Press me', command=close_window)
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Why does exception still raise?

UPD I use Python 2.7

Comment: *"safe"* is a somewhat misleading name for what is a rudimentary [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy).

Comment: It does not reproduce for me it gets caught in Python 3.4

Comment: @AnandSKumar, I use Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tkinter main process loop is not brought down by exceptions and does not propagate them further. Hence, the exception never reaches till the `with` statement (since tkinter itself catches and reports the exception and then stops execution).

You will need to create a decorator to catch those exception and log them or do whatever logic you want to do.

Example -

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
from contextlib import contextmanager

class exceptioncatcher: # <---the decorator
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            print 'Exception catched1'


@exceptioncatcher
def close_window(): 
    window.destroy()
    raise Exception


@contextmanager
def safe():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception:
        print 'Exception catched'

with safe():
    window = Tk()
    button = Button(window, text='Press me', command=close_window)
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

With the above code, when I click on the `Press` button, it logs `Exception catched1` for me and exits.

Also, It is not good to do `except:` you should give the exception you want to catch (or atleast `except Exception:` ).

Comment: `def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): try: return self.function(*args, **kwargs) ...`

Comment: @AnandSKumar Many thanks! That is what I don't know about Tkinter windows.